# What does this code using [].filter.call do?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I’m learning javascript and trying to write code that sorts a list, removing elements if they meet certain criteria.

I found this snippet that seems promising but don't have a clue how it works so I can adapt it to my needs:

```
list = document.getElementById("raffles-list").children; // Get a list of all open raffles on page
list = [].filter.call(list, function(j) {
    if (j.getAttribute("style") === "") {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Can you guys help me learn by explaining what this code block does?

Comment: Where did you copy it from? What does it do, what problem did it solve for you? What part exactly is unclear, surely you understand bits of it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's getting all the children of the "raffles-list" element, then returning a filtered list of those that contain an empty "style" attribute.

The first line is pretty self-evident - it just retrieves the children from the element with id "raffles-list".

The second line is a little more complicated; it's taking advantage of two things: that [], which is an empty array, is really just an object with various methods/properties on it, and that the logic on the right hand side of the equals sign needs to be evaluated before "list" gets the new value.

1. Uses a blank array in order to call the "filter" method
2. Tells the *filter* to use *list* as the array to filter, and uses *function(j)* to do the filtering, where j is the item in the list being tested
3. If the item has a style attribute that is empty, i.e. has no style applied, it returns true.

Edit:
As per OP comment, *[].filter* is a prototype, so essentially an object which has various properties just like everything else. In this case filter is a method - see **[here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)**. Normally you just specify an anonymous function/method that does the testing, however the author here has used the *.call* in order to specify an arbitrary object to do the testing on. It appears this is already built into the standard *filter* method, so I don't know why they did it this way.

Comment: I sort of gather that, I was wondering if you could help with what the [].filter.call etc does, as in in separate bits so I can use parts for future codes and learning

Comment: So I could improve this code further by just removing the 'unneeded' .call part?

Comment: @Taazar it doesn't appear so - it looks like you have two options - either say list.filter(function(j) { ...}), or the way the author did it. If you take out the .call, it will evaluate against the empty array.

Comment: `list.filter` will not work, because `list` is an `HTMLCollection`, which is not an `Array`. Therefore it doesn’t have the `filter` prototype method. This is the reason why the empty array needs to be created in order to get the `filter` method from the `Array` prototype. You could not take away the `call` part, except if you converted `list` to an `Array` before (e.g. `Array.from(list)` — not supported by all browsers). The part with “`[].filter` is a prototype” from this answer isn’t very clear. `filter` is a _prototype method_ from `Array.prototype`. `.call` isn’t specific to `filter`.

Answer (score 1):

Array like objects are some of javascript objects which are similar to arrays but with differences for example they don't implement array prototypes. If you want to achieve benefits of array over them (for example like question filter children of an element )you can do it this way:

```
Array.prototype.functionName.call(arrayLikeObject, [arg1, [arg2 ...]]);
```

Here in question array like is html element collection; and it takes items without any styling.

Answer (score 0):

1. `list` is assigned a *collection* of elements that are children of the `raffles-list` element
2. `list` is then reassigned by filtering its elements as follows

   1. an empty array is `filter`ed by `call`ing it with the parameter `list` and a callback function. The formal parameters for `call` are `this` (which is the `list`) and optionally further objects (in this case a callback function)
   2. The callback function receives a formal parameter `j` and is called for each element
   3. If the element's value for the `style` attribute is empty the element is retained in the array. Otherwise it is discarded.
3. At the end `list` should contain all elements that don't have a value for its `style` attribute