# Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function(form) What is this doing?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I am having a hard time fully understanding how this code works. This is just form validation code copy and pasted from bootstrap.

My issue starts with this line 
var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function(form)

It seems to me it is creating an array called validation containing any element with the class name "needs-validation". Then is it calling the anonymous function and passing in the entire form and running the subsequent lines of code

```
 form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
     if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
     event.preventDefault();
     event.stopPropagation();
     }
```

on each of the elements that contain the class name "needs-validation"?

```
<script>
    // Example starter JavaScript for disabling form submissions if there are invalid fields
    (function() {
      'use strict';
      window.addEventListener('load', function() {
        // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
        var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('needs-validation');
        // Loop over them and prevent submission
        var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function(form) {
      form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
        if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
          event.preventDefault();
          event.stopPropagation();
        }
        form.classList.add('was-validated');
      }, false);
    });
  }, false);
})();
```

This code successfully validates the inputs on a form. I just don't understand how it works.

Comment: It's not clear why `filter()` was chosen, nor what the point of `validation` is (if this is really the code then `validation` will just be an empty array). Where is this code _actually_ taken from? I'd be very surprised if this was somewhere in the bootstrap source like you claim (unless I'm misunderstanding you).

Comment: The callback isn't returning anything. So, it ends up being something like: `for (const form of forms ) { if (form.checkValidity() === false)......}` It's a way of using array methods on array-like objects [What does this code using \[\].filter.call do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38033320) and [Who can help to explain this JavaScript algorithm \[\].filter.call()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40531611)

Comment: @adiga Do you have any idea why they chose filter over forEach? It seems an odd choice.

Comment: @IceMetalPunk not sure. It acts just like `forEach` in this scenario.

Comment: @adiga Except it also has the overhead of creating a new array and then... never using it. forEach would not have that issue.

Comment: This is taken directly from bootstraps website if you look under Components then forms then on the right hand side select validation. It is under a subheading called custom styles. I has the effect of if you have lets say several text boxes and you don't fill in one of them, you can display a message underneath the text box of "looks good" or "please enter name" and that message will show up rather than it allowing the form to be submitted.

Comment: P.S. Why would I lie about that, PR?

Answer (score 7):

The method `document.getElementsByClassName` return a `HTMLCollection`, in first look it similar to Array but `HTMLCollection` doesn't has methods `.filter`, `.map`, `reduce`, etc.

So for using these methods, we need to convert `HTMLCollection` to an array.

Or we can use, specific of javascript: `Array.prototype.filter` go by iterable on an object, and if you look in details on `HTMLCollection` what `document.getElementsByClassName` returns it has keys and it's `iterable`. So we can call method `Array.prototype.filter.call(` and pass as a context (first parameter) our `HTMLCollection`, second parameter will be a functions what will be calls for each element in collection.

Little bit more about call() method https://gomakethings.com/what-the-hell-is-the-call-method-and-when-should-you-use-it/

Comment: @Jacqueline is it clear answer or need more details?