# Unable to iterate into hidden value field

Tags: javascript, pug

I am using Pug templating engine and tried to iterate Users array into a form with hidden input value.
When tried to retrieve the value via document.getElementById('custId').value - I can only console.log the first value successfully, the second and other values are not even appearing in the console.

iteration is working fine with a tag. I can console.log all values.

```
a(href=`/approve-user/${user._id}`) by viewroute
```

but with hidden input

```
input(type="hidden" id="custId" name="custId" value=`${user._id}`)       
button.btn.btn-primary#approve-btn #{user._id}
```

I am only able to console.log the first hidden value of user._id.

PUG file:

```
block content
    .container
        h1= title      
        .content
        table.table
            thead.thead-light
                tr
                    th(scope="col") Name
                    th(scope="col") Email
                    th(scope="col") Tier
                    th(scope="col") Approve via viewRoute
                    th(scope="col") Approve via Axios
            tbody
            each user in users
                tr
                    td= user.name
                    td= user.email
                    td= user._id       
                    td 
                        a(href=`/approve-user/${user._id}`) by viewroute
                    td 
                        form#approve
                            input(type="hidden" id="custId" name="custId" value=`${user._id}`)       
                            button.btn.btn-primary#approve-btn #{user._id}
                    tr

        p.text-warning.text-center= msg
```

JS file:

```
const approveSellerTest = () => {
    let id = document.getElementById('custId').value;
    console.log('From approveSellerTest, hidden value: ', id);     
};

const approveBtn = document.querySelector('#approve');
if (approveBtn) {

    approveBtn.addEventListener('click', e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        approveSellerTest();
    });
};
```

Refer to attached output screen.

[Screenshot of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zAOlT.png)

If I click on the first blue button, console.log displays the first user._id on the console. However, if I click on the second or third blue button, the console doesn't display anything, not even undefined.

Expected result:
Clicking on 2nd blue button should display in console the user._id of 5d544fa7578a7e23eb268b2b and click on 3rd blue button, should display in console the user._id of 5d5457eb27dff0257c016ace

Comment: `id` must be unique on the page

Comment: and `document.querySelector('#approve');` return only first element by this selector

Answer (score 1):

I think two problems here:

1) The value of each id attribute must be unique in a document.

and better use a `submit` instead `button` in forms

```
td 
  form(data-id="approve")
    input(type="hidden" id="custId-${user._id}" name="custId" value=`${user._id}`)       
    submit.btn.btn-primary #{user._id}
```

2) `document.querySelector('#approve')` return only first element by this selector, need to use a `document.querySelectorAll`:

```
const approveForms = document.querySelectorAll('[data-id="approve"]');

if (approveForms && approveForms.length) {
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(approveBtns, function(form) {
    form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
        approveSellerTest();
        e.preventDefault();
    });
  });
};
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

Here I answered why need to use `Array.prototype.forEach.call` for elements which we get from `querySelectorAll` method

[Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function(form) What is this doing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57419277/array-prototype-filter-callforms-functionform-what-is-this-doing/57420594#57420594)

Answer (score 0):

Can you add the generated DOM?
Maybe a problem with having multiple forms, and input with same id (`#approve` and `#custId`). Then your JS may only initialized on first Form.

Try with unique ids, then your JS has to define your `approveSellerTest` event handler to work with **any** forms. You can use CSS classes instead of ids.

(not a pug user here)